# Adding a Slider in a Chart

Tags: wpf, charts, slider

I have a need to have a movable slider on line charts. The way it should work is as follows:

1. Slider/Cursor should be parallel to Y-axis i.e. vertical axis
2. When user moves this slider, corresponding/intersecting Y values on all graphs show up in labels just like a stock ticker chart.

3 the intersection of slier with the graph line ,the value should be displayed in textbox

Thanks,
avinash

Comment: Which charting library are you using? What have you tried already?

Comment: @avinash, welcome to `StackOverflow`. Please note that it is customary to *not* use capital letters throughout your question title... as such, I have edited it.

Comment: @metacircle i am using a line chart having x and y axis , i want a vertical line in the graph which is movable .